# facebook applinks back navigation

Tags: ios, facebook, applinks

Does anyone know if current facebook ios app support the applinks back navigation (http://applinks.org/documentation/#uxguidelinesrecommendations)? i.e. when my app open a page on native facebook app, is there a way to go back to my app from facebook?

Comment: It does not at this point.

Comment: Hi Ming Li, do u guys have any plan to add it in?